# Question about minimax risk sparse sparse condition

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, sparse

I am studying statistical leaning theory.

Especially the paper **"Minimax rates of Estimation for High Dimensional Linear
regression over $l_q$ balls"**  by Garvesh Raskutti .et.al.

In the right end of the page 6990 (proof of lemma 4)

there is the situation below

$H=\left\{−1,0,1\right\}^d$ => $d$ dimensional vector whose elements is one of  $\left\{-1,0,1\right\}$

$H^∗=\left\{v∈h:||v||_o =s\right\} $

$||v||_o$
 is the number of nonzero elements of $v$

that is $H^*$ is the set of all $s$ sparse vector of $d$ dimension

and for $v\in H^*$ , $B(v,s/2)=\left\{v ′ ∈H^∗ :p(v,v')≤s/2\right\}$,

$p(v,v′)$ is hamming distance between $v,v′$, that is $B(v,s/2)$

$d≥3s/2$

I need to prove $|B(v,s/2)|≤$ ${d}\choose{s/2}$ $2^(s/2)$.

At this paper the proof is not presented.

---

Oh I made some mistakes

$H=\left\{−1,0,1\right\}^d$

=> the set of all $d$ dimensional vector whose elements is one of {−1,0,1}

---

I made another mistake

$H^∗ =\left\{v∈H:||v||_o =s\right\}$

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I made some mistakes

$H=\left\{−1,0,1\right\}^d$

=> the set of all $d$ dimensional vector whose elements is one of {−1,0,1}

Comment: This is not an answer. You should be editing your question if you have a correction.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.